# How to pass arguments to bash command

Tags: bash

I try to pass this result in the third command -d argument, But i failed.

```
$ cat asnlookups_domains_ip.txt | awk '{print $1}' | amass intel -whois -d 
flag needs an argument: -d
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: `xargs` should help

Comment: (OT: [Useless use of `cat`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat))

Comment: Please [don't post images of text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `xargs`:

```sh
cat asnlookups_domains_ip.txt | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -n1 amass intel -whois -d
```

It passes the standard input as arguments after your command.

Comment: Hi  `xargs` output like `example.com evilzone.com`  . I need to pass one by one domain name on -d argument.

Comment: @Shuvasaha Try `xargs -n1 …`.

Comment: @Biffen It is working as I need it. Thank you very much

Comment: I edited the answer to include the "-n1"